# How to set default value in drop down in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Here in my array there are 5 values that I am getting in "Options" props , but I want to set default value Please Select ,that I have defined in state.
          And trying to get in Value props . But its getting error . `Label of undefined`
          Basically when I open my page in drop down "Please Select" and after that that array value should come .
          Please suggest .
below select field I have created separate component .

```
<AndroidPicker
            mode="dropdown"
            iosIcon={<Icon name="chevron-down" type="MaterialCommunityIcons"/>}
            placeholder=""
            placeholderStyle={{ color: "#bfc6ea" }}
            placeholderIconColor="#007aff"
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
            selectedValue={value}
            onValueChange={(e) => onChange.bind(that, this.props, e)()}
          >
            {
              options.map((item, indx) => {
                let { label, value } = item;
                return <AndroidPicker.Item key={indx} label={label} value={value}/>;
              })
            }
          </AndroidPicker>

    this.state={
    religionValue:'Please Select'
    }

    religion: Array(5)
    0: {name: "Hindu", code: "H", __typename: "TroubleTicketMasterCode"}
    1: {name: "Christian", code: "C", __typename: "TroubleTicketMasterCode"}
    2: {name: "ISLAM", code: "I", __typename: "TroubleTicketMasterCode"}
    3: {name: "Others", code: "O", __typename: "TroubleTicketMasterCode"}
    4: {name: "Not Disclosed", code: "ND", __typename: "TroubleTicketMasterCode"}

 religionChanged = (key, val) => {
        this.handlereligionChanged({ field: "religionValue" }, val);
    };

    handlereligionChanged = (props, e) => {
        let tempObj = this.state.religionValue;
        tempObj[props.field] = e;
        this.setState({ religionValue: e });
    };

    let religionOptions = [];
            religion.map(({ code: value, name: label }) => {
                religionOptions.push({ value, label });
            });


        <SelectField
             label="Religion"
             value={this.state.religionValue}
             options={religionOptions}
             node="Religion"
             onChange={this.religionChanged}
             that={this}
             setIcon={true}
              />
```

Comment: could you share your `religionChanged`?

Comment: hi . i have just updated my question u can chek now

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SelectField` attribute called `defaultValue`. Check out the docs at [react-md site](https://react-md.mlaursen.com/components/select-fields#default-values-and-controlling)